# Pandas not displaying all columns when writing to

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to export a dataset that looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Province_State |   Admin2     |  03/28/2020  |  03/29/2020  |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| South Dakota   | Aurora       |      1       |      2       |
| South Dakota   | Beedle       |      1       |      3       |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

However the actual CSV file i am getting is like so:

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| Province_State  |  03/28/2020  |  03/29/2020  |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| South Dakota    |      1       |      2       |
| South Dakota    |      1       |      3       |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Using this here code (runnable by running createCSV(), pulls data from COVID govt GitHub):

```
import csv#csv reader
import pandas as pd#csv parser
import collections#not needed
import requests#retrieves URL fom gov data


def getFile():
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-    19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series    /time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv'
response = requests.get(url)
print('Writing file...')
open('us_deaths.csv','wb').write(response.content)
#takes raw data from link. creates CSV for each unique state and removes     unneeded headings    
def createCSV():

    getFile()
    #init data
    data=pd.read_csv('us_deaths.csv', delimiter = ',')
    #drop extra columns
    data.drop(['UID'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['iso2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['iso3'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['code3'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['FIPS'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    #data.drop(['Admin2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['Country_Region'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['Lat'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['Long_'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(['Combined_Key'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    #data.drop(['Province_State'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.to_csv('DEBUGDATA2.csv')


#sets province_state as primary key. Searches based on date and key to create new CSVS in root directory of python app
data = data.set_index('Province_State')
data = data.iloc[:,2:].rename(columns=pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore')
for name, g in data.groupby(level='Province_State'):
    g[pd.date_range('03/23/2020', '03/29/20')] \
        .to_csv('{0}_confirmed_deaths.csv'.format(name))
```

The reason for the loop is to set the date columns (everything after the first two) to a date, so that i can select only from 03/23/2020 and beyond. If anyone has a better method of doing this, I would love to know.

To ensure it works, it prints out all the field names, inluding Admin2 (county name), province_state, and the rest of the dates.

However, in my CSV as you can see, Admin2 seems to have disappeared. I am not sure how to make this work, if anyone has any ideas that'd be great!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: @AMC thank you for your feedback. I have made adjustments, please let me know if anything can be improved.

Comment: _However the actual CSV file i am getting is like so:_ Can you share the actual data as it appears in the file?

Comment: Also, why convert the column names to Datetime objects? Can you explain what the loop over the groupby is for?

Comment: @AMC I have shared the data as it looks in the file (with datapoints removed... there are more dates and counties. If you want to see these, let me know or run the program)

The reason for the loop is to set the date columns (everything after the first two) to a date, so that i can select only from 03/23/2020 and beyond. If anyone has a better method of doing this, I would love to know.

Comment: _If anyone has a better method of doing this, I would love to know._ So would I, I'm messing around with the data/program now, and is it just me or is the format a bit of a pain?

Comment: @AMC Someone helped with the date time part, so it confuses me a little too. If you know a way to do what i am trying to do without this, please share. Or at the very least, forget about the date formatting, if you know how to get it to group correctly as well as show the admin2 column, i'd love to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210703/discussion-between-sammy-and-amc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
data = data.set_index('Province_State')
```

to

```
data = data.set_index((['Province_State','Admin2']))
```

Needed to create a multi key to allow for the Admin2 column to show. Any smoother tips on the date-range section welcome to reopen

Thanks for the help all!